# How to create a Customized Typeahead Easily

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in scripting. I have some experience of using jQuery, Angular.JS and Bootstrap 3.

I want to create a customized Typeahead like this-[image: 1]

Can anyone please suggest a easy solution for that?

Can anyone provide me a tutorial which can be easily understandable and easy to use?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: have you considered bootstrap typeahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are using bootstrap you can just use [Bootstrap typeahead](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead). There are tons of tutorials online and but both [Blattchat tutorial](http://blattchat.com/2013/01/09/bootstrap-typeahead/) and [tutorial republic](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-typeahead.php) seem to have nice tutorials on those two.

Comment: have considered angularJS UISelect ? Im sure this can be achieved using UISelect